# Using Net::HTTP.get_print in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use `Net::HTTP.get_print` in a rails app to get the response from a URL, and print the URL on the page. My controller contains:

```
uri_string = "www.example.com"
uri = URI.parse(uri_string)
@contents = Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)
```

Then the matching .html.erb file contains:

```
<%= @contents %>
```

The resulting page is blank, even when I use a dummy URL like `"http://www.google.com"`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.7 (OS X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing is displayed, because get_print outputs to STDOUT and returns nil. Meaning, you'll be able to see the output in your log, but not on your web page.

use `@contents = Net::HTTP.get(uri)` or similar